# C#: Cdecl DllExport with a pointer to class instance in the arguments

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I'm thinking of writing an addon for a software called SmartDVB. It requires me to export the following function (this is a c++ example):

```
BOOL RegisterAddOn(UINT iAddOnId, IAddOnInterfaces *pInt, AddOnSettings &settings) {
    /* ... */ 
    return TRUE;
}
```

Where `IAddonInterfaces` is an abstract class (interface):

```
class IAddOnInterfaces {
public:
    virtual HRESULT AddSectionFilter(UINT uiAddOnId, UINT pid, BYTE *filter, BYTE *mask, BYTE length, DeviceSettings *pDev) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT RemoveSectionFilter(UINT uiAddOnId, UINT pid, DeviceSettings *pDev) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT AddFilter(UINT uiAddOnId, UINT pid, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT RemoveFilter(UINT uiAddOnId, UINT pid, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT GetChannel(UINT uiAddOnId, CHANNEL *chn, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT GetTransponder(UINT uiAddOnId, SATELLITE *sat, TRANSPONDER *t, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT SetTransponder(UINT uiAddOnId, SATELLITE sat, TRANSPONDER t, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT CreateOSDElement(UINT uiAddOnId,  OSDWindowType type, ULONG &ulId, OSDWindowInfo &info) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT ChangeChannel(UINT uiAddOnId,  CHANNEL &chn, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT RegisterOSDEvents(UINT iAddOnId, IAddOnOSDEvents *pEvents) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT RegisterMenuEvents(UINT iAddOnId, IAddOnMenuEvents *pEvents) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT RegisterChnEvents(UINT iAddOnId, IAddOnChnEvents *pEvents) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT DoDVBCmd(UINT iAddOnId, BYTE pCmd, UINT uiLen, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT DoDiseqc(UINT iAddOnId, CHANNEL &chn, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT RecordBusy(UINT iAddOnId, BOOL *bBusy, DeviceSettings *pDev=NULL) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT GetDeviceSettings(UINT iAddOnId, DeviceSettings &Dev) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT GetSignalStrength(UINT iAddOnId, LONG *lStrength, DeviceSettings *Dev) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT GetSignalQuality(UINT iAddOnId, LONG *lQuality, DeviceSettings *Dev) = 0;
};
```

And `AddOnSettings` is a struct:

```
typedef struct _AddOnSettings{
    HINSTANCE hInst; // SmartDVB application instance
    HWND hwnd;
    TCHAR name[256]; // addon name
    HMENU menu;      // addon popup menu
    WORD idmenustart;
} AddOnSettings;
```

In c#, I defined the structure as

```
using HINSTANCE = System.IntPtr;
using HWND = System.IntPtr;
using HMENU = System.IntPtr;

/* ... */

public unsafe struct AddOnSettings{
    HINSTANCE hInst; // SmartDVB application instance
    HWND hwnd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 256)]
    char[] name; // addon name
    HMENU menu;      // addon popup menu
    ushort idmenustart;
};

/* ... */
```

However, I still need to define the class somehow, so that it could be exported.

Finally, I want to have something this:

```
    [DllExport("RegisterAddOn", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static bool RegisterAddOn(uint iAddOnId, IAddOnInterfaces* pInt, ref AddOnSettings settings)
    {
        /* ... */
        return true;
    }
```

The thing is that when I do that, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('ChannelSwitchCS.IAddOnInterfaces')    D:\Work\coding\projects\buster\smartdvb\ChannelSwitchCS\ChannelSwitchCS\Class1.cs   102 28  ChannelSwitchCS
```

P.S. I don't ask for the full solution, I just need to understand this particular case, i.e. how (and if it is even possible) to have a pointer to the class instance in the exported function. So, I do realize that I will have to convert all other structures and classes that are used within the methods of `IAddOnInterfaces`.

Comment: I think you cannot do this only in C#. You need to implement SmartDVB addon interface in native C++, and then to wrap it for C# using C++/CLI or PInvoke.

Comment: An interface is already a pointer, just declare the argument as `IAddOnInterfaces pInt`.  Note that the [MarshalAs] attribute on the *name* field is wrong, it must be UnmanagedType.ByValTStr.  Looks like a COM interface btw.

Comment: @HansPassant you are right about the _name_ field, I fixed that. But unfortunalely it turned out to be impossible to work with the class directly in the c# code, so I changed everything to IntPtr and created a wrapper c++ dll (it provides the standalone functions that are mapped to the class instance methods; so I pass the class instance pointer as a first parameter and then call the needed function with the passed arguments). This is exactly like Alex Farber wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had to use PInvoke and had the need to pass instances of classes around as pointers, I wrote a simple wrapper for the unmanaged code that I would be using in C++ that only accepted primitive types and arranged them into whatever types were needed.

When it came to passing the pointers to the instances of classes, I used `IntPtr` and everything worked how I would expect it to.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the only solution. I created a simple wrapper dll in c++ that provides access to the class instance methods in the following way: `obj->function(param)` will be accessed via exported c++ function `wrapper(obj, param)` and then called this way from c# (where obj will be of `IntPtr` type).

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal, but it does the job!